# Editing resources.groovy file programmatically

Tags: grails, groovy

I am trying to access and update the parameters in beans inside resources.groovy through a controller. The bean is defined as:

```
beans{
    property(Property){bean ->
      companyName = "Old Company"
    }
}
```

I tried doing this:

```
//params.companyName is updated from view
def beanReturned =  Holders.applicationContext.getBean("property")
beanReturned.putAt("companyName",params.companyName)
```

But seems like above code only allows to read but not update. The property companyName is unchanged. 
How can I update the fields inside beans through controller?

Comment: Could you please describe why you need that?  This feels very dangerous and a desperate attempt to make something work via the wrong means.  Yet alone, that you most likely wont be able to write to the resource.groovy once it is deployed (can only read easily from jars). If you want to 'theme' an application, i'd rather do that via a persistent storage (e.g. the DB you already use or an external config file and use that via a service.

Comment: @cfrick I have to make the fields in resources.groovy updatable by admin for default values. Several beans have been constructed for same class and each beans contain different values for fields.